# Make timeline easier to access with a redirect to the timeline if "/timeline" is added to the end of the question URL

Tags: feature-request, timeline, redirection

I occasionally use the timeline on questions. However, it can be quite a bother to get to on my phone sometimes; I need to select and delete all the text on the right of the ID and also question, which can take a while and be kind of glitchy with long titles. I'd like it if going to `/questions/{ID}/{name-of-questions}/timeline` would redirect to `/posts/{ID}/timeline`.

Comment: The edit history URL is the quickest and easiest URL to change into the timeline URL btw.

Comment: @RobertLongson the other post is asking for a link/button on the question page. This is asking for a shortcut (adding /timeline to the post url). They are related, but not duplicates.